# Separation of variables for the Laplace equation on a disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have the equation $$\bigtriangleup u=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta}=0$$ where 
$0<r<1$ , $-\pi< \theta \leq\pi$
and $$u(1,\theta)=g(\theta)$$
This is my solution.
To solve this I assume the solution is of the form $$u(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$$
I then work out $u_{r}$,$u_{rr}$, $u_\theta$ and $u_{\theta \theta}$ and I plug these into $\bigtriangleup u$ to get $$\frac{1}{r} R' \Theta +\frac{1}{r^2}R\Theta''+R''\Theta=0$$

However my lecture notes get $$\frac{-r}{R}(rR')'=\frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}=k$$
How do you get this result?

My lecture notes then look at 3 cases.
Case 1: K=0. The lecture notes then say from this we get $$\Theta=a\theta+b$$ and $$R=c_1 ln r+c_2$$
I now understand how to get these expressions. But the notes then say: With boundary/consistency conditions, $\Theta=b$, $=c_2$ $\rightarrow$$u(r,\theta)=1$
What does this mean?

We then look at the case for when $k=-p^2<0$ and $k=p^2>0$.

Looking at $k=p^2>0$ we then I get $$T'=-p^2T$$ and $$x''=-p^2x$$Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r} R' \Theta + \frac{1}{r^{2}} R \Theta '' + R'' \Theta &= 0 \\
\implies r R' \Theta + R \Theta '' + r^{2} R'' \Theta &= 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(multiplying through by $r^{2}$)}\\
\implies r R' \Theta + r^{2} R'' \Theta &= -R \Theta '' \\
\implies r R' + r^{2} R'' &= -R \frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(dividing both sides by $\Theta$)}\\
\implies r (R' + r R'') &= -R \frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} \\
\implies r (rR')' &= -R \frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{as $(rR')' = R' + r R''$} \\
\implies \frac{-r}{R} (rR')' &= \frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} \ \ (*) \\
\end{align}$$

Now at $(*)$, we have functions of **different** variables, but the functions are equal to each other. The **only** way this can occur is if the LHS and RHS are equal to a constant, **the same constant**, which your lecturer has called $k$, which is also known as the **separation constant**.

So we should rewrite $(*)$ as

$$\frac{-r}{R} (rR')' = \frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} = k \ \ (**)$$

(**Note:** Some books use $k^{2}$ for the separation constant, some use $-\lambda$, the main thing to remember is that it is just a constant so it doesn't matter what you call it).

Now to your expressions. From $(**)$ and what I explained earlier, we know that

$$\frac{-r}{R} (rR')' = k \ \ (1)$$

and

$$\frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} = k \ \ (2)$$

If $k = 0$ then $(1)$ implies

$$\begin{align}
\frac{-r}{R} (r R')' &= 0 \\
\implies (r R')' &= 0 \\
\implies r R' &= C \\
\implies R' &= \frac{C}{r} \\
\implies R &= C \ln r + D \\
\end{align}$$

where $C$ and $D$ are constants. If $k = 0$ then $(2)$ implies

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\Theta ''}{\Theta} &= 0 \\
\implies \Theta '' &= 0 \\
\implies \Theta ' &= A \\
\implies \Theta &= A \theta + B \\
\end{align}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: If you need anymore help, just comment below. Also, if you are happy with this answer could you please accept it.

Comment: In the next step the notes say : with boundary/consistency conditions, $\Theta=b$, $R=c2$ $\rightarrow$     $u(r,\theta)=1$. Where does this come from?

Comment: Also what if the case was $k=p^2 >0$ and $k=-p^2<0$?

Comment: @user232183 Make an edit to your post with the new information/questions and I'll answer them.